Is it true that $\dot{H}(t)\sim H(t)$, and if so, why?
In the context of working with the FRW metric in Cosmology, I'm trying to reproduce the results of a paper where an expansion of the metric in terms of perturbations is performed. The author gives a result and then states that "corrections are suppressed by further powers of $H^2\vec{x}^2$".
However, the corrections that I get come in two different forms: some of them are, indeed, powers of $H^2\vec{x}^2$, but others are powers of $\dot{H}H\vec{x}^2$, where the overdot denotes the derivative with respect to time. This leads me to believe that, for some reason, $\dot{H}(t)$ can be considered to be of the same order as $H(t)$.
Is it true? It doesn't seem intuitive. How can I prove this?

Since $\dot{H}$ isn't the same dimension as $H$, it can't be of the same order as $H$. It can, however, be of the same order as $H^2$, or $H/\tau$ with $\tau$ an appropriate time constant.

$\dot H$ is not comparable to $H$, since the two have different dimensions. However, for a flat cosmology, you can use the two Friedmann equations to show that $\dot H$ is of order $-H^2$ (except for a dark energy phase when $\dot H=0$).
Intuitively this means that the time scale for the expansion rate to change significantly ($\sim H/\dot H$) is of order a Hubble time ($1/H$) and hence of order the age of the universe.


Wild Feather wrote: "This leads me to believe that, for some reason, $\dot{H}$ can be considered to be of the same order as $H$."

In a radiation dominated universe we have
$$\rm H=+\frac{1}{2 \ t} \ \ \& \ \ \dot{H}=-\frac{1}{2 \ t^2}$$
while in a matter dominated universe it is
$$\rm H=+\frac{2}{3 \ t} \ \ \& \ \ \dot{H}=-\frac{2}{3 \ t^2}$$
so they differ by the $\pm$ sign and a factor of $\rm t$. In a dark energy dominated universe $\rm H$ would be constant and $\rm \dot{H}$ therefore $0$. For our universe with all three components combined we have

The $\rm x$ axis for the time $\rm t$ is in Gyr and the $\rm y$ axis for $\rm H$ and $\rm \dot{H}$ in SI units.
